# In $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ with $p$ prime and $p = 1 \text{ mod } 3$, prove that there exists an element of order 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $p$ be prime, and $p = 1 \text{ mod } 3$. Consider $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$.

Prove that in $\mathbb{F}_p$ there exists an element of order 3. Use that to conclude that $X^2 + X + 1$ has a root in $F_p[X]$.

---

I am preparing for an exam and this is one of the example questions. I've thought about it for a bit, but to be honest I don't really know where to start. Can somebody give me a hint, so that I know where to start looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** if $k$ is a field and $G \leq k^\times$ a finite subgroup, then $G$ is cyclic.

More hints below (don't read them without thinking about this for a while):

> by Cauchy's theorem, you only need $3$ to divide the order of a group $G$ to get that it has an order $3$ element.

> We know that $\Bbb F_p^\times$ has $p-1$ elements and by hypotehsis $3 \mod p-1$, so there exists some $\omega$ such that $\omega^3 = 1$. Plug $\omega$ in $x^2+x+1$, play around with this.

> We have $(x-1)(x^2+x+1) = x^3-1$. Evaluate in $\omega$, use that $\omega \neq 1$ to conclude that it is a root of $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Oh wow thank you! The first hint helped me figure it out :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Write $p=3m+1$. Then $x^{p-1}-1=x^{3m}-1=(x^3-1)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ has degree $3(m-1)$.

The  $3m+1$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ are exactly the roots of $x^{p}-x$. They cannot all be the roots of $x(x-1)q(x)$, which has degree $3m-1$. Therefore, there are at least $2$ roots of $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.